# How to make text visible on small screen resolutions like 1366 x 768 using bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, screen-resolution

I am using bootstrap columns where i have a problem with screen resolution, Below select field text is not visible completely when i used screen resolution 1366 x 786.

How can i resolve this issue using bootstrap ?

main.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        <div class="form-group">
        <label for="oplossValDate" class="col-md-5 {{requiredstr}}">
        OpLoss Validation Dates:</label>
        <div class="col-md-7" ng-if="rcsaCycleDTO.cycStatLkupCode === 'RA_CYC_SETUP'">
            <select class="form-control" name="oplossValDate"
                id="oplossValDate"
                ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.opLossValidationDateKey"
                ng-change="OplossFromAndToDate()"
                ng-options="OplossValidationDateOption.id as OplossValidationDateOption.text for OplossValidationDateOption in OplossValidationDateOptions">
                <option value="">Select...</option>
           </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        //code for these columns
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove this: `class="col-md-7"` from the `<div>`.

Comment: If i dont specify bootstrap class `col-md-7` it will break and change position to next line

Comment: See the answer below, it explain what I was about to explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the form tag around you `<div class="form-group">` and remove the `class="col-md-5"` and `class="col-md-7"` like that:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="oplossValDate" class="{{requiredstr}}">
        OpLoss Validation Dates:</label>

        <select class="form-control" name="oplossValDate"
            id="oplossValDate"
            ng-if="rcsaCycleDTO.cycStatLkupCode === 'RA_CYC_SETUP'"
            ng-model="rcsaCycleDTO.opLossValidationDateKey"
            ng-change="OplossFromAndToDate()"
            ng-options="OplossValidationDateOption.id as   OplossValidationDateOption.text for OplossValidationDateOption in OplossValidationDateOptions">
            <option value="">Select...</option>
        </select>
      <div class="col-md-6 fieldHeight">
        //code for these columns
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-inline) for more information.

Comment: I copied your code exactly and apply but No luck for some reason select field is moving to next line and breaking other fields.

Comment: replace the parent div of select tag  with a span tag. Div tag is a block tag.

Comment: I edit the answer, copy the code from above. It should be work.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this site for all kind of code doubt: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp